# Proper way to reference ReadTheDocs page (with or without .html in path)

Tags: markdown, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I have a github project called [amrlib](https://github.com/bjascob/amrlib) where I link to my ReadTheDocs pages in the main README.  For some reason I now seem to need to use links without `.html` in them.  However, at some point in the past the `.html` was required.  I'm now wondering what is the "right" way to do this and why does it appear to have changed.  I've looked at other projects' github pages and their links use `.html` at the end, so why not mine?

```
https://amrlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/      <-- works today
https://amrlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html  <-- now produces error page
```

I'm using simple markdown (.md) files with mkdocs and I'm not doing anything fancy.

Just wondering why the `.html` paths no longer seem to work and what is the "right" way to set this up.